# how to set a default value on a data does not exists on the table

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query sample which is to get the latest `status` of a `user` from another table

you can see it here : [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e12c04/1)

So if an `accountId`  exists in `heat table` it will get the lastest status but if the `accountId` doesn't exist on the table the supposed `status` was `-1`

but when I tried to run the query the `accountId` that wasn't on the heat table it returns `NULL` instead of `-1`

I tried to replace the `IFNULL` to `IF` or `COALESCE` but still, it returns `NULL`

Comment: mySQL version???

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: sorry i wasn't able to read the meta about posting queries. thank you for this reminder..

Comment: Note that an edit button is provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for your problem:

```
SELECT M.accountid,IFNULL(HS.status,-1) as status
FROM members M
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT accountID,MAX(dateCreated) as MaxDate 
FROM Heat
GROUP BY accountID) H
ON M.accountID = H.accountID
LEFT JOIN Heat HS
ON H.accountId = HS.accountId AND H.MaxDate = HS.dateCreated
WHERE M.isDeleted != 1 
ORDER BY M.accountid ASC;
```

Demo for the same (Sample Data Structure is based on columns given in query):

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/385e79/1)

Comment: can i ask which part of my query did i made a mistake??

Comment: Try to run this query which you are using to generate status column and you will come to know that this is not generating any status for ids for which it is showing null:   

SELECT IFNULL(H.status,-1) as status from heat H 
JOIN (SELECT accountId, max(dateCreated) maxdate from heat group by accountId) S 
ON S.accountId = H.accountId and S.maxdate = H.dateCreated

Comment: I have made a change in your query to get the desired output. You can check it here: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e12c04/7
  I myself don't think the way you have written the query is good. The query you have written to generate a column by using another select query in place of a column which can be done easily using a single query.

Comment: i got a problem with the query here [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c6bfc/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c6bfc/1)  cause from my record the `dateCreated` had duplicate value so when i tried to run the query it returns an error.. 
ER_SUBQUERY_NO_1_ROW: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Can you give me query where it is giving error since the above one is not showing any error.

Comment: you can try it here [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82771d/1) ..

Comment: I have checked and find out that you are getting 2 status values for accountID - 202004 which can be corrected in the below link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82771d/7